# pro asp.net 4.5 in c# book by adam freeman sportstore

Tags: asp.net

just wondering did anybody complete the sport store application in this book, i am having a problem with the data binding in the orders page for the admin, i want to pull in the product id from the order lines table but i keep getting errors, it working correctly for the quantity but i can seem to get the product id to bind. i have tried the following code but this is not working for me at the moment

```
  **<td><%# Item.OrderLines.Product_ProductID %></td>**
```

it says i am missing a definition in the orderline

Comment: You should probably post more relevant detail about your code.  What is the definition of Item and OrderLine(s)?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `OrderLines` is of type List most likely. So the list doesn't have a definition of `Product_ProductID`. You should rather make a loop for `Item.OrderLines` and then you can access each order line of the order with its product. At second, take a look at your `OrderLine` model. Does it contain `Product_ProductID`? Most likely it has `Product` property 
references to `Product` model  which contains `ProductID`. So after all, your code would look like:

```
**<td><%# Item.OrderLines[i].Product.ProductID %></td>**
```